# ViewController instance doesn't get deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, instance, viewcontroller

I am facing a really mind-breaking problem..

So my application was working just fine, until now..

---

The app has a **TabController: with 5 viewControllers**

On this TabController I have a timer that fetches data every 10 seconds

This data is being sent with **notifications** to one of its child VCs called `"WorldMessages"`, which then updates it's tableView

I don't know how or why, but whenever I log out / log in in my application, the WorldMessages ViewController instance get stuck..

So for example after 5 relogin, I have 5 WorldMessages VC in the memory..

> // Relogin means that the TabController and its childViews are getting
>   destroyed, and then logging in back creates a new instance of
>   TabController //

---

I have a clue that it is because of the threading, but I am not sure. When I delete a few lines, it is working okay. Can anyone help me out?

( If i delete those lines in the **WorldMessages viewController**:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: tableViewDeletes, with: .fade)
tableView.insertRows(at: tableViewInserts, with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Then the app is working fine.. )

**TabController, the function that gets called every 10 seconds:**

```
@objc func fetchWorldMessages(scrollToTop: Bool){

        worldMessagesFetch.fetchWorldMessages() { response, worldMessageData in
            if let response = response {
                if response.type == 1 {
                    // Fetched data
                    if let worldMessageData = worldMessageData {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .updateWorldMessages, object: nil, userInfo: worldMessageData)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Can not fetch data
                    self.handleResponses.displayError(title: response.title, message: response.message)

                    WorldMessagesStore.shared.clear()
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reloadWorldMessagesTableView, object: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**The WorldMessages viewController:**

```
@objc func notification_updateWorldMessages(notification: NSNotification){

        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

        if let newWorldMessages = notification.userInfo?["newWorldMessages"] as? [WorldMessage], let newDeleteArray = notification.userInfo?["newDeleteArray"] as? [Int], let newAppendArray = notification.userInfo?["newAppendArray"] as? [Int], let newWorldMessagesCount = notification.userInfo? ["newWorldMessagesCount"] as? Int, let worldMessagesCount = notification.userInfo? ["worldMessagesCount"] as? Int {

            if (newWorldMessagesCount == 0 && noWorldMessages.count == 0){
                noWorldMessages = [1]
                tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 1...1), with: .automatic)
            } else if (newWorldMessagesCount != 0 && noWorldMessages.count != 0) {
                noWorldMessages = []
                tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 1...1), with: .automatic)
            }

            var count = 0
            count = newWorldMessagesCount


            if count != 0 {

                var tableViewDeletes : [IndexPath] = []
                for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: -1, by: -1) {
                    // WHAT SHOULD BE DELETED
                    WorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.remove(at: i)
                }

                var tableViewInserts : [IndexPath] = []
                for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: -1, by: -1) {
                    // WHAT SHOULD BE ADDED
                    WorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.insert(newWorldMessages[i], at: 0)

                }

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: tableViewDeletes, with: .fade)
                tableView.insertRows(at: tableViewInserts, with: .fade)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }

        }

    }
```

**Image:**

(In my app "WorldMessages VC" is called **Main VC**)

So after 2 relogin It get stuck 2 times: (You see 2 instances)

[image]

**VIDEO of the bug:** (demonstrating that if I delete those 4 lines everything works fine)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xfTzbZplBA

Comment: What you mean by  `I have 5 WorldMessages VC in the memory`  ?

Comment: what do you do when relogin

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish updated

Comment: What do you do to signup are you present signup controller or set as root

Comment: I'm assuming that `WorldMessages` is either a subclass of `UITableViewController` or at least conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. If you remove the lines that update the table view, then those protocol methods won't be called. Therefore, I suspect those methods are creating a retain cycle. The most likely culprit would be the methods for `UITableViewDataSource`, specifically `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: The memory graph in your video also proves this (around 0:35). The cell objects are pointing to your view controller. This means that they have a reference to your view controller. And the view controller also has references to them (indirectly, because they are children of the table view). It definitely looks like you're creating a retain cycle between the view controller, the table view, and the table view cells.

Comment: @ABeard89 adding a new reply

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying and re-reading the replies I got, I realized something.

I have gestureRecognizers on my custom cells, therefore I had to add a delegate to them: and (for now, It seems) this caused the problem

```
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class WorldMessageCell: SwipeTableViewCell {
    var worldMessageData : WorldMessage!

    @IBOutlet var bubbleView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var bubbleButton: UIButton!

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    var delegate2: WorldMessageDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Handling press, longpress
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bubbleTapped))
        self.bubbleButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bubbleLongPressed))
        longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)


        self.bubbleButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }


    @objc func bubbleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate2?.bubbleTappedHandler(sender: sender)
    }

    @objc func bubbleLongPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate2?.bubbleLongPressHandler(sender: sender)
    }
}

protocol WorldMessageDelegate {
    func bubbleTappedHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    func bubbleLongPressHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
}
```

The delegate was strong. After replcaing

```
var delegate2: WorldMessageDelegate?
```

with

```
weak var delegate2: WorldMessageDelegate?
```

And changing the protocol

```
protocol WorldMessageDelegate {
```

to

```
protocol WorldMessageDelegate: class {
```

Everything works fine.

May I be correct?

Comment: @ABeard89 what do you think?

Comment: You may be correct, yes. Having a strong reference to your delegate probably creates a strong reference cycle. Your viewcontroller holds a reference to the cell, via the tableview, and the cell holds a reference to the viewcontroller (if the viewcontroller acts as the cell's delegate). If both of these references are strong, the viewcontroller and the cell won't ever be released from memory.

Comment: @andlin thank you! Yes I understand it now, what a complicated thing is to make programs.. eh

Comment: That looks like it to me! I suspected a property needed to be changed to weak.